# Crontab command not register the top command result into the output file

Tags: 16.04, cron, top

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and I created a sh file.

```
cd /home/malus
echo "______________________________________________________________________" >> /home/malus/top.txt 
date >> /home/malus/top.txt 
sudo top n 1 o %MEM u mysql | grep mysql >> /home/malus/top.txt
```

I want to save the information of MySQL into a file (top.txt) + date + seperator

When I run the sh file all is correct and the output file contains 3 lines.

But, when I let crontab to run the script the output file does not contain the top output and instead I have an empty line (I have seperator + date but not top output).

For crontab I used this command:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

And the contents are:

```
00 * * * * /home/malus/top.sh
15 * * * * /home/malus/top.sh
30 * * * * /home/malus/top.sh
45 * * * * /home/malus/top.sh
```

**Edited Part:**

The output when I run the script file directly (./top.sh), as you see there are some bizarre characters (in Notpad++ they are as ESC)

```
______________________________________________________________________
Wed Apr 10 11:24:33 EDT 2019
(B[m  636 mysql     20   0 3681720 1.233g   4236 S   0.0 63.3 113:35.71 mysqld                                                                           (B[m[39;49m[K
```

The output of crontab, as you see there is no output for top command:

```
______________________________________________________________________
Wed Apr 10 11:30:01 EDT 2019
```

***ANSWER***

I did these changing according to [steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver) and [terdon](https://askubuntu.com/users/85695/terdon) (Thanks to you both)

The script file:

```
echo "______________________________________________________________________" >> /home/malus/top.txt 
date >> /home/malus/top.txt 
sudo top n 2 -b o %MEM u mysql | grep mysql >> /home/malus/top.txt
```

For running the crontab as root:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

The crontab contents:

```
00 * * * * /home/malus/top.sh 2>>/home/malus/top.err
15 * * * * /home/malus/top.sh 2>>/home/malus/top.err
30 * * * * /home/malus/top.sh 2>>/home/malus/top.err
45 * * * * /home/malus/top.sh 2>>/home/malus/top.err
```

Comment: Try using the full path to the top command `/usr/bin/top` instead of `top`

Comment: @Parto Thanks for your answer, but not working

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the output of `top n 1 o %MEM u mysql | grep mysql`.

Comment: The `(B[m` sequences are formatting characters - if you want to avoid them, run `top` in batch mode (`top -b`)

Comment: @steeldriver that's actually the problem, almost certainly. You need the `-b`. Malus, does it work if you use `top b n 1 o %MEM u mysql | grep mysql`? Also, [you probably want `n 2` and not `n 1`](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=174619). `top -n 1` doesn't show the right output (it's the value since boot, not the current one).

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks, the problem of strange characters is solved by `-b` but the other problem exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have added this to root's crontab (you ran `sudo crontab -e`), so why are you running `top` with `sudo`? Everything in that crontab will be run as root. More importantly, you should ***never*** run a command with `sudo` unless that command needs to be run as root. The `top` command never needs root access, every user sees the same output, so the `sudo` there is pointless. The `cd` is also pointless, there's no need to move into the `/home/malus` directory. So change your script to:

```
echo "______________________________________________________________________" >> /home/malus/top.txt 
date >> /home/malus/top.txt 
top n 1 o %MEM u mysql | grep mysql >> /home/malus/top.txt
```

That said, I don't see any other problem in your file. The `top` command is in `/usr/bin` and `/usr/bin` [is in cron's PATH](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/401621/22222), so you don't need a full path for it. What is happening is probably that the command has no output.

For example, if I run your `top` on a system where the `mysql` user is running something, I get:

```
$ top n 1 o %MEM u mysql | grep mysql
 2379 mysql     20   0 28.915g 5.612g  13516 S   0.0  4.3   2038:41 mysqld
```

However, if the `mysql` user isn't running anything, there is no output since the `grep mysql` won't match:

```
$ top n 1 o %MEM u mysql | grep mysql 
$
```

So, if the `date` is being correctly added to `/home/malus/top.txt`, then the lack of output from `top` just means the `mysql` user wasn't running anything when the crontab was run.

The only other explanation is that you have your `top` and/or `grep` commands in a non-standard location. If so, run `type top` and `type grep` to see where they are:

```
$ which top grep
/usr/bin/top
/bin/grep
```

And then use those paths:

```
echo "______________________________________________________________________" >> /home/malus/top.txt 
date >> /home/malus/top.txt 
/usr/bin/top n 1 o %MEM u mysql | /bin/grep mysql >> /home/malus/top.txt
```

But that's really unlikely unless you have moved these and they aren't in `/usr/bin` or `/bin`.

Finally, to debug it further, change the crontab so that it also keeps the error output:

```
00 * * * * /home/malus/top.sh 2>>/home/malus/top.err
15 * * * * /home/malus/top.sh 2>>/home/malus/top.err
30 * * * * /home/malus/top.sh 2>>/home/malus/top.err
45 * * * * /home/malus/top.sh 2>>/home/malus/top.err
```

Then see if anything is written to `/home/malus/top.err`.

---

The error you had, `TERM environment variable not set.` is because the environment variable `$TERM` isn't set in the cron's shell session, and `top` need that to know what kind of output to produce:

```
$ unset TERM
$ top
TERM environment variable not set.
```

A simple workaround, therefore, is to set it in your script:

```
echo "______________________________________________________________________" >> /home/malus/top.txt 
date >> /home/malus/top.txt 
TERM=xterm top n 1 o %MEM u mysql | grep mysql >> /home/malus/top.txt
```

Comment: Thanks @terdon for explaining in detail. I did all the modifications that you asked me, unfortunately did not work. I can explain more here: 1- If I run the top.sh with or without sudo it works. but when crontab run it does not work. which is why I add also `sudo` for crontab and I had tested before without `sudo top` (just `top`) 2- As you said `-b` removed the characters, thanks 3-I found an error message as output: **TERM environment variable not set.** 4-I'm pretty sure that mysql is running, I want to run the crontab for checking the memory that mysql take.

Comment: @MalusJan please add all of these details to your question so everyone can see them. Also, make sure to use `n 2`, otherwise the memory results [will be wrong](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=174619). But do you still have the same issue with the `top` output not in the file even when using `b`?

Comment: I'll modify the question. In the error file (top.err) there is an error message: **TERM environment variable not set**

Comment: @MalusJan Ah! Yes, that is from `top` and it means it cannot run! Of course, there's no `TERM `variable set in the cron environment! Does it work if you add `TERM=xterm` to your script? Alternatively, just don't use `top` (it isn't the right tool for this anyway), use `ps -o %mem | grep [m]ysql`